# Data hidden in jpg

Tags: security, reverse-engineering, decoding, steganography, ctf

I am currently looking for hidden data in a jpg file but I have no clue on how to operate.

There is a jpg file containing text in a format I have never seen before :

```
-ne \xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10\x4a\x46\x49\x46\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x60\x00\x60\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00\x43\x00\x06\x04\x04\x05\x04\x04\x06\x05\x05\x05\x06\x06\x06\x07\x09\x0e\x09\x09\x08\x08\x09\x12\x0d\x0d\x0a\x0e\x15\x12\x16\x16\x15\x12\x14\x14\x17\x1a\x21\x1c\x17\x18\x1f\x19\x14\x14\x1d\x27\x1d\x1f\x22\x23\x25\x25\x25\x16\x1c\x29\x2c\x28\x24\x2b\x21\x24\x25\x24\xff\xdb\x00\x43\x01\x06\x06\x06\x09\x08\x09\x11\x09\x09\x11\x24\x18\x14\x18\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\x24\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x01\x8e\x03\x4e\x03\x01\x22\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01\x7d\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12\x21\x31\x41\x06\x13\x51\x61\x07\x22\x71\x14\x32\x81\x91\xa1\x08\x23
-ne \x42\xb1\xc1\x15\x52\xd1\xf0\x24\x33\x62\x72\x82\x09\x0a\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x11\x00\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x03\x04\x07\x05\x04\x04\x00\x01\x02\x77\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x04\x05\x21\x31\x06\x12\x41\x51\x07\x61\x71\x13\x22\x32\x81\x08\x14\x42\x91\xa1\xb1\xc1\x09\x23\x33\x52\xf0\x15\x62\x72\xd1\x0a\x16\x24\x34\xe1\x25\xf1\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49
```

This is just the beggining of the file as there is at least a hundred lines.

The file type given by the command `file` : `file.jpg: ASCII text, with very long lines`

I tried some of the common tools to identify any patterns or hidden data like exiftools, strings, xxd but I found nothing.

If you have any idea on what to do it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a challenge of CTF, there are some common way to find out flag.

First try to find flag in file metadata, like description of file field
you can also try tool: `stegsolve.jar`.

In more advance sence, stego info hidden with some math calulation, give this tool a try: [zsteg](https://github.com/zed-0xff/zsteg)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem here, but if your file actually starts with a backslash character followed by the characters `x`, `f`, `f`, `\`, `x`, `d`, `8` and so on, then what you're looking at is the binary content of a JPG file that has been converted into ASCII text.

If so, you need to convert this back into binary data. For example, in Linux or MacOS, you could do this by entering the following on the command line:

```sh
echo -ne '\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10\x4a\x46\x49\x46\x00\x01...etc...' > img.jpg
echo -ne '\x42\xb1\xc1\x15\x52\xd1\xf0\x24\x33\x62\x72\x82...etc...' >> img.jpg
```

(Note: `>` sends the results to a new file, and `>>` appends to the end of the file)

Or alternatively in Python:

```py
with open("img.jpg","wb") as f:
    f.write(b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10\x4a\x46\x49\x46\x00\x01...etc...')
    f.write(b'\x42\xb1\xc1\x15\x52\xd1\xf0\x24\x33\x62\x72\x82...etc...')
    # and so on for all the other lines
```

Either way, you should end up with a file called img.jpg containing the image you're after.